# Cannot install bundles behind proxy with authentication in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I am not able to install any bundles because in my college there is a proxy with authentication. I have been through all questions here on SO regarding this, but they are not helping me in any manner.

I am using version **3.2.13** right now.
Even after initializing the env variables by `export http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port>`

I get the following error every time I try to install any bundle `The bundle API is not responding.`

Has someone been able to come with any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say much for proxies, but you should be able to install bundles by downloading their .zip file from github. I'll walk you through swiftmailer bundle, for instance:

1. http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/swiftmailer
2. You should notice the install command is `php artisan bundle:install swiftmailer`.
3. `swiftmailer` is the name of the folder you should create inside your bundles directory.
4. There's a link to the bundle repository on Github at the sidebar. Download it as .zip.
5. Simply unzip its content inside that folder you just created.
6. Register the bundle on `bundles.php` like usually.